# Is it possible to use spot colors in TikZ graphics?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, color

Using ConTeXt and Metapost, it is fairly easy to define spot colors and use them in an image:

```
\starttext
\definecolor[MyRed][c=0,m=1,y=1,k=0]
\definespotcolor[RedSpot][MyRed][p=1,e=MyRed]

\startMPpage
  draw unitsquare scaled 10cm;
  fill fullcircle scaled 8cm shifted(5cm,5cm) withcolor \MPcolor{RedSpot};
  setbounds currentpicture to boundingbox currentpicture enlarged 2mm;
\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

The PDF color channels may be separated using GhostScript and then summarized using ImageMagick's `montage` utility:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffsep -r300 -sOutputFile=separation.tif <output pdf>
montage -label "%f" -density 300 <output pdf> *.*.tif -geometry 600 output.png
```

*NOTE: There is a bug in GhostScript 9.0 -- 9.02 that breaks the tiffsep device by making it unable to load color profiles*

The resulting summary shows that the PDF consists of a black frame and a circle that occupies a spot channel:

[image: Color Separation of ConTeXt output]

---

A similar effect [can be achieved using XColor and PS-Tricks](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.text.tex/LurkNpbgF7I/discussion):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{spot_color.pro}
TeXDict begin
/RedSpotCMYK [0 1 1 0] def
/RedSpotSpot (RedSpot) def
/RedSpotDef RedSpotCMYK aload pop RedSpotSpot findcmykcustomcolor def
/XC@RedSpot{RedSpotDef 1.0 setcustomcolor}XCdef
end
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[prologue]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage[tightpage,active,psfixbb]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\definecolor{RedSpot}{cmyk}{0 1 1 0}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
  \psframe (0,0) (10cm,10cm)
  \pscircle[fillcolor=RedSpot,fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none] (5cm,5cm){4cm}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Compiled with LaTeX and converted to PDF:

```
latex pstricks_spot
dvips -h tex.pro -h xcolor.pro -h spot_color.pro pstricks_spot
ps2pdf pstricks_spot.ps
```

This gives a similar color separation:

[image: Color Separation of PSTricks output]

---

However, if I try to swap TikZ for PSTricks in the above process:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{spot_color.pro}
TeXDict begin
/RedSpotCMYK [0 1 1 0] def
/RedSpotSpot (RedSpot) def
/RedSpotDef RedSpotCMYK aload pop RedSpotSpot findcmykcustomcolor def
/XC@RedSpot{RedSpotDef 1.0 setcustomcolor}XCdef
end
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[prologue]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[tightpage,active,psfixbb]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{RedSpot}{cmyk}{0 1 1 0}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
  \draw            (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
  \fill[color=RedSpot] (5,5) circle (4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

*NOTE: [TikZ 2.10 is broken](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17080/does-tikz-2-1-no-longer-work-with-the-preview-package) when combined with the Preview package and `dvips`*

The red circle no longer occupies a separate channel:

[image: Color Separation of TikZ output]

---

Therefore, my question is:

> Given that XColor can enable spot colors for PSTricks graphics and TikZ also uses XColor, is it possible to use spot colors in TikZ graphics?

If so, I will be asking a follow-up question about doing so without rendering through Postscript (i.e using `pdflatex` instead of `latex`/`dvips`/`ps2pdf`)

Comment: Two possibly related questions/answers: [PDF colour model and LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9961/2693) and
[Why DOESN'T the color of overlapped region between opaque red and green objects become opaque yellow?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8081/2693)

Comment: I gave a patch for using TikZ and spot colors together in [this answer][1].


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145127/12850

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(I'm guessing a lot here.)   I *think* that it is down to the way in which PGF inserts colours in to the output file.  To see this, it's worth reviewing the levels in the TikZ/PGF system.

1. At the top, we have TikZ.  This is the *frontendlayer* and defines the syntax that the user (usually) uses.  It's job is to translate user-friendly stuff into a simpler state ready for further processing.
2. In the middle, we have PGF.  This is the *basiclayer*.  This is where all the detail takes place.  Here, things are done in a machine/program-friendly way.  The full power of TeX is used to do some heavy machinery.  All the path decorations and similar are done here.  The goal of this layer is to translate what the user *wants* in to basic *path entities*.
3. At the bottom, we have the drivers.  These form the *systemlayer*.  Here is where the PGF code is interpreted in to specific instructions.  These have to be specific to the planned output type.

So the thing to remember in this is that when you say `\fill[color=RedSpot]` then that is a *TikZ* command to set the colour to `RedSpot` which then gets further interpreted by PGF and then the driver.  Chasing definitions through, we find that `color=RedSpot` calls `\pgfsetcolor` which calls `\pgf@setcolor` which calls `\pgfsys@color@<model>`.  This is now a *driver* level command.  Its definition, say for CMYK, is

```
\def\pgfsys@color@cmyk@stroke#1#2#3#4{\pgfsysprotocol@literal{#1 #2 #3 #4 K}}
```

from which we can see (and tracing back through the definitions, this gets clearer) that even if we've defined a colour name, it is the CMYK values that get put in the file.

The point is that PGF cannot know that it is possible in PDF to alias colours, because it doesn't know that the final output will be PDF.  So it translates the colours to their raw values.  And `0 1 1 0 setcmykcolor` *isn't* the spot colour.

A lot of the above is speculation, I'll admit.  Here's my evidence for this being the case.  If you compile the `PSTricks` file above and look at the PS, you'll find that the drawing code is:

```
  tx@Dict begin STP newpath /ArrowA { moveto } def /ArrowB { } def
 0.8 SLW TeXDict begin XC@black end   142.26378 142.26378 113.81102
.5 CLW mul sub 0 360 arc closepath  gsave TeXDict begin XC@RedSpot
end  1. .setopacityalpha  fill  grestore end
```

But if you compile the `TikZ` version and look at the PS, you'll find:

```
 0 1 1 0 setcmykcolor

 141.73404 141.73404 moveto

 255.12128 141.73404 moveto

 255.12128 204.35689 204.35689 255.12128 141.73404 255.12128 curveto

 79.11119 255.12128 28.3468 204.35689 28.3468 141.73404 curveto

 28.3468 79.11119 79.11119 28.3468 141.73404 28.3468 curveto

 204.35689 28.3468 255.12128 79.11119 255.12128 141.73404 curveto

 closepath
```

So the `RedSpot` gets put *literally* in to the PS from `PSTricks` but is translated back to `0 1 1 0` internally by PGF first.

The clincher is to do the following.  Edit the PS file and replace the `0 1 1 0 setcmykcolor` by `XC@RedSpot`.  Then do the `gs` and `montage` stuff, and you get:

[image: spot colours from TikZ]

which is what you wanted.

However, editing the postscript isn't a great way to do this!  Here's what I think you'd have to do to use spot colours in TikZ.  I think you'd have to define a new *colour model*, say `spot`.  You'd then tell PGF that the `spot` colour model is to be treated specially in that the *name* of the colour is to be used (or at least `XC@<name>`).  To define a spot colour, you could (I think) use `xcolor` to *define* it using one model and then convert it to another.  That would ensure that the definition got in to the PS file (which it does already).  I don't know how to do all those steps, because it relies on knowing how `xcolor` works and I don't know much about that.  But that's what I would do.

Comment: Sorry for letting this one sit for so long. Looks like the loss of spot colors is a price PGF pays for multi-driver abstraction. Thanks for the excellent write-up and additional info!

Comment: @Sharpie & Andrew Since I am not advanced enough to understand above, I will just put a simple question: I wrote a book in LaTeX that uses two colours, black and bluish one and includes **lots** of pictures in TikZ.  Printing company wants me to provide PDF that uses black and a Pantone colour.   Can I do that?  I did find the appropriate Pantone colour...

Comment: @Pygmalion I'm afraid that the above represents the absolute limit of what I know how to do.  I recommend that you ask a new question about it to see if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Andrew Stacey: this would mean creating a duplicate question.

Comment: @Pygmalion No, it would be a follow-up question.  This question is finished with as Sharpie has accepted this answer.  But, it would seem, Sharpie was more interested in the "why" than the "how".  You need the "how" so you can ask a new question, referencing this one, and explaining that you need to actually be able to do this.