# Problem including TikZ in journal template

Tags: tikz-pgf, templates, ieee-style

I am trying to use an IEEE journal template of this [URL_of_IEEE_Access](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-access/).

I want to use the `tikz` and the `pgfplots` packages.
However, I just including the `tikz` package in the provided template produce error compiling.

The error is this:

[image]

Looking for a solution I have found [*tikz package causing an error in IEEE access template*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440422/tikz-package-causing-error-in-ieee-access-template)
.
I have tried to follow the instructions given by `@yado` but I can not make the solution to work.
I can not generate the mentioned `xspotcolor.sty` from the `.dtx` file and the `xspotcolor` package does not exist.

I would like to find a solution to this problem. A solution which allows the use of TikZ and pgfplots in the Access Template.

Comment: Instead of fiddling with the class, which can cause your paper to be rejected, just simply prepare the figures in a separate `.tex` file using an article class, e.g., with the same font and fontsize and include pdf figures using `\includegraphics{..}`.

Comment: @AboAmmar That is a way to bypass the problem and is a solution. The problem is that I have many TikZ figures and some are multiplots.

Comment: IMHO, this is still solvable using a separate `.tex` file using a `standalone` class with multiple `tikzpicture` environments inside, each `tikzpicture` environment will generate one figure in its own pdf page. After generating all figures in a single pdf file, just extract all pages to separate pdf files and you can include them easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, this is solvable using a separate .tex file using a `standalone` class with multiple `tikzpicture` environments inside, each `tikzpicture` environment will generate one figure in its own pdf page. After generating all figures in a single pdf file, just extract all pages to separate pdf files and you can include them easily into your document.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle  (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which will generate a pdf file like this:

[image]

Finally, extract the pages into separate files and include them into your document using `\includegraphics{..}`.

Comment: Thank you. I am doing this. It is tedious in my paper with so many figures :-) but it solves the situation.