# Compile error of the IEEE Access template

Tags: texlive, templates, document-classes

I am going to write a paper of the IEEE Access LaTeX format uploaded in this page https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-access/ .

But I got the following error message from the TeXShop compiler.

```
 This is ptex2pdf[.lua] version 20170622.0. Processing access.tex This is e-pTeX, Version 3.14159265-p3.8.0-180226-2.6 (utf8.euc) (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=platex)  restricted \write18 enabled. entering extended mode (./access.tex pLaTeX2e <2018-04-01>+1 (based on LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2) Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded. (./ieeeaccess.cls (./IEEEtran.cls Document Class: IEEEtran 2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
    -- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
    -- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/ (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
    -- Using 8.5in x 11in (letter) paper.
    -- Using DVI output.
    -- This is a 10 point document. (I search kanjifont definition file: . . )

    LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JT1/mc/m/it' undefined (Font)        using `JT1/mc/m/n' instead on input line 1090.


    LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JY1/mc/m/it' undefined (Font)        using `JY1/mc/m/n' instead on input line 1090.


    LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JT1/mc/bx/it' undefined (Font)       using `JT1/mc/bx/n' instead on input line 1090.


    LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JY1/mc/bx/it' undefined (Font)       using `JY1/mc/bx/n' instead on input line 1090.

    ) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/spotcolor/spotcolor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))) 
./ieeeaccess.cls:128: Undefined control sequence. \AddSpotColor
    #1#2#3#4->\def \obj { 0 R}\pdfobj {<</C0[0 0 0 0]/FunctionType... l.128 ...SpotSpace 3015\SpotSpace C} {1 0.3 0 0.2}

?  Process aborted
```

Does anyone have ideas to fix this issue?

My computer’s OS is  macOS Mojave, and I’m using TeXShop to compile the LaTeX file. I installed my LaTeX package including TeXShop with MacTeX.

I can successfully compile and create papers of IEEE Transaction format (IEEEtrans.cls).

Thank you

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440422/tikz-package-causing-error-in-ieee-access-template. Also using `ptex` might be part of the problem, to find the exect issue you can try to get it working with `pdflatex` first.

Comment: You may just use IEEE Transaction format (IEEEtrans.cls), it is accepted as well.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, Marijn, KJO and  Bora Onat. I could compile with pdfLaTeX not upLaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access template was designed to work with pdflatex. The author is trying to use it with ptex, which uses different fonts and different color commands.

The author should be advised to use pdflatex if possible. If not, he can work with the IEEEtran.cls version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Bora Onat.