# Conflict between necessary packages

Tags: packages, incompatibility

I am using a template with this preamble:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

I also need to add these packages:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
```

However there is a fatal conflict in compilation (I think between `tikz` and `graphicx`. How could I solve it?

Comment: millions of documents every day load tikz and graphicx. If you get an error show a small example, and show the exact error that you get, copied as text from the log file.

Comment: also please give a link to ieeeaccess.cls which is not in the standard tex distributions

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440422/tikz-package-causing-error-in-ieee-access-template/440513#440513

Answer (score 2):

I found a copy of the class at

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/beatrizgoa/latex/master/ieeeaccess.cls

I will assume the version you are using is similar.

The class breaks LaTeX in several ways but in particular here it redefines the `\year` TeX primitive which breaks any date calculations in TeX (and so in pgfmath)

The class has

```
\def\year#1{\gdef\theyear{#1}}
```

which is to say the least not a good idea.

You should report this to the class maintainers but

```
\let\realyear\year
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\let\classyear\year
\let\year\realyear

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Probably patches it enough so that LaTeX isn't completely broken.

If you are reporting it

```
\def\textit#1{{\it #1}}%
\def\textbf#1{{\bf #1}}%
```

Should be removed as well.