# Title, section headings disappears when I use \usepackage{forest} with IEEE Access template

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

When I include a  \usepackage{forest} all colored text title, section headings disappears with IEEE Access journal template
How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The developers of the `ieeeaccess` class had the brilliant idea of redefining the primitive `\year`; this breaks `expl3` and `pgf`.

Comment: Once fixed the issue with `\year`, the problem of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29017/4427 pops out, which is the incompatibility of `xcolor`, required by Ti*k*Z/PGF, and `spotcolor`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two main issues because `forest` needs `expl3` and Ti*k*Z/PGF.

Other packages might cause the same error, for instance `arabtex`.

The first issue is the brilliant idea of the developers of the `ieeeaccess` document class of redefining the primitive `\year`.

The second issue is that the class loads the very experimental and little tested `spotcolor` package, which is incompatible with the major package for colour support, namely `xcolor`, which is what PGF needs and loads. See [Using colors defined with spotcolor.sty in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29017/4427)

A preamble that somewhat cures this is as follows:

```
% save the meaning of \year
\let\texyear\year

\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}

% temporary fix for loading expl3 and PGF
\let\ieeeaccessyear\year
\let\year\texyear

\usepackage{forest}

% undo the fix and define a color compatible with xcolor
\let\year\ieeeaccessyear
\definecolor{accessblue}{RGB}{0,105,154}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: +1. But I believe there is a typo. I think you forgot the `s` in curses. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In light of the previous answer, use `\usepackage{orcidlink}` in the preamble as follows:

```
\let\texyear\year
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\let\ieeeaccessyear\year
\let\year\texyear
    \usepackage{orcidlink}
\let\year\ieeeaccessyear
\definecolor{accessblue}{RGB}{0,105,154}
\begin{document}
```

Then use \orcidlink

```
\author{\uppercase{Author's Name}\orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0000}\authorrefmark{1}, \IEEEmembership{Member, IEEE}}
```

This solved the title and heading disappearance issue for me

Comment: Welcome to TexSE.

Comment: this approach works for me for ieee access template.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I used regular image to display orcid logo next to authors in ieee access journal template

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[allbordercolors={0.5 1 1}]{hyperref}

\author{\uppercase{Author 1}  \href{https://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000}{\includegraphics[scale=0.0035]{orcid.png}} \authorrefmark{1},
\uppercase{Author 2} \href{https://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000}{\includegraphics[scale=0.0035]{orcid.png}} \authorrefmark{2}
}
```