# I face this problem when I use optidef package

Tags: optidef

When I use  optidef package with a Journal template. This messages appear:

```
1- Missing number, treated as zero. ...nst:Nn \c_sys_year_int { \tex_year:D }
2- Missing = inserted for \ifnum. ...nst:Nn \c_sys_year_int { \tex_year:D }
3- Missing number, treated as zero. ...nst:Nn \c_sys_year_int { \tex_year:D }
4- You can't use `\numexpr' in vertical mode. ...nst:Nn \c_sys_year_int { \tex_year:D }
5- Missing \begin{document}. ...nst:Nn \c_sys_year_int { \tex_year:D }
6- Missing number, treated as zero. ...nst:Nn \c_sys_year_int { \tex_year:D }
```

Also : Blank page added to the beginning of the pdf text.

The journal template can be found here:
    https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/turk-j-elec-eng-&-comp-sci-template

```
\documentclass{elektr}
\usepackage[long]{optidef}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
urlcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue}
\usepackage[all]{xy,xypic}
\usepackage    {amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsgen,amsopn,amsbsy,theorem,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{eufrak,amscd,bezier,latexsym,mathrsfs,enumerate}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,noresetcount ]{algorithm2e}

\year{}
\vol{}
\fpage{}
\lpage{}
\doi{}

\title{Title}

\author[Authorsh ]{
\textbf{Ahmad H. $^{1}$}\\
 $^{1}$Department 
    \\ [1.8em]

    \rec{.2019}
\acc{.2019}
\finv{..2019}
}


\input{elksty.tex}


\setcounter{page}{1}

\makeatother
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.91} 
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}Abstract


\keywords{Key words}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{Int}

\section{Problem Formulation}
\begin{mini!} [!T]
    {x_{u}{^t},y_{u}{^t},z_{u}{^t}:~ t \in  T}{P^{t}_{t_{total}}}
    {}{}
    \label{Sim_opt}
    \addConstraint{{P^{t}_{t_{total}}}\leq P_{t_{UAV_{max}}}}
    \addConstraint {(x_{min}, y_{min}, z_{min} )\leq( x_{u}{^t},y_{u}{^t}, z_{u}{^t} )}{\leq (x_{max}, y_{max}, z_{max}),}
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example which reproduces your errors?

Comment: \documentclass{elektr}
\usepackage[long]{optidef}

Comment: @ahmadHani: Please add the minimal example to your post above, not as a comment. Just adding `\documentclass{elektr}` etc. is not enough.

Comment: Where are `elektr.cls` and `elksty.tex` available?

Comment: @Christian , Ok

Comment: I guess the problem is the same as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470144/4427

Comment: Journal template : https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/turk-j-elec-eng-&-comp-sci-template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's another case where the developers of the class had the not very good idea of redefining the TeX primitive `\year`. This can and *does* break many packages that use `\year` to refer to the current year. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470144/4427 for another similar case.

```
\let\texyear\year

\documentclass{elektr}

\let\elektryear\year
\let\year\texyear

\usepackage[long]{optidef}
\usepackage[all]{xy,xypic}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsgen,amsopn,amsbsy,theorem,graphicx}
\usepackage{eufrak,amscd,bezier,mathrsfs,enumerate}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,noresetcount ]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue
}


\elektryear{}
\vol{}
\fpage{}
\lpage{}
\doi{}

\title{Title}

\author[Authorsh ]{
\textbf{Ahmad H. $^{1}$}\\
 $^{1}$Department 
    \\ [1.8em]

    \rec{.2019}
\acc{.2019}
\finv{..2019}
}


\input{elksty.tex}


\setcounter{page}{1}

\makeatother
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.91} 
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}Abstract


\keywords{Key words}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{Int}

\section{Problem Formulation}
\begin{mini!} [!T]
    {x_{u}{^t},y_{u}{^t},z_{u}{^t}:~ t \in  T}{P^{t}_{t_{total}}}
    {}{}
    \label{Sim_opt}
    \addConstraint{{P^{t}_{t_{total}}}\leq P_{t_{UAV_{max}}}}
    \addConstraint {(x_{min}, y_{min}, z_{min} )\leq( x_{u}{^t},y_{u}{^t}, z_{u}{^t} )}{\leq (x_{max}, y_{max}, z_{max}),}
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```

I also removed `epsfig` and `latexsym` that should never be used in newer documents. Also `hyperref` should be loaded last.