# Glossaries package incompatible with documentclass{lni}

Tags: pdftex, glossaries

I have an issue with the latex glossary package, in that it is incompatible with the lni documenttype.

The following code

```
\documentclass{lni}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\title{test}
\author{author}
\date{December 2020}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

gets me especially this error:

```
You can't use `\let' after \the.

\new@ifnextchar #1#2#3->\let 
\reserved@d = #1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \rese...
l.15 \end{document}
                   
I'm forgetting what you said and using zero instead.
```

as soon as I use anything that is not lni, or remove the \makeglossaries, it works no problem.
I am using the pdftex compiler.
Any ideas?

Comment: Where can we find `lni.cls`?

Comment: I am using overleaf but I think its this one: https://github.com/gi-ev/LNI/blob/master/lni.cls

Comment: You could consider connecting with the class author (details located in [`lni.cls`](https://github.com/gi-ev/LNI/blob/master/lni.cls)).

Comment: I have contacted the author and will post any fix or alternative here.

Comment: Thanks for the report. I identified the problem. It is the redefinition of `\year` at the beginning of the document. I'll try to find a fix for that without loosing compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

The class redefines `\year` to be used an normal macro, which is not a good idea, because its value is used by packages like `glossaries`. A workaround for your problem is to set the year explicitly in your document, e.g. `\year=2020` and to revert `\year` to its original definition (which is saved as `\@rigyear`) after it has been used, i.e. after `\maketitle`:

```latex
\maketitle
\makeatletter\let\year\@rigyear\makeatother
...
```

Comment: Reverting the definition of `\year` is enough. You do not have to set the year. You could even use the intended way of `\year{2019}` as long as this happens after `\begin{document}` and before `\maketitle`

Comment: BTW: The `lni` class is available on CTAN and as well part of MiKTeX and TeX Live

Comment: I fixed the files on GitHub (https://github.com/gi-ev/LNI/)

Comment: You should remove that redefinition of `\year` as soon as possible. I understand that this can invalidate older documents, but keeping it is likely to break ***many*** packages. You're not alone, unfortunately: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474073/4427) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470103/4427) I see no reason whatsoever for making `\year` into a user-space command when it can be more semantically `\submissionyear`, `\publicationyear` or similar.

Comment: This class as many others has its history. Moreover as article class for a specific journal it has a rather limited scope of additional packages. It has been used by many users without problems over the last years. Using `glossaries` seems a bit odd to me, but in general you are right. It was a wrong decision and should be corrected.

Comment: Version v1.7 of the `lni` class drops `\year` and uses `\yearofpublication` instead.