# Title and section headings do not appear when LaTeX code is compiled

Tags: sectioning

My code was working fine on my old laptop running Windows 8. When I changed to a new laptop running Windows 10, the title and section headings are omitted in the PDF. I am using `Texmaker_5.0.4_Win_x64` and `basic-miktex-20.6.29-x64` on the new laptop. The old laptop is running the same Texmaker but `basic-miktex-2.9.7351-x64`. I tried using the latter MiKTeX on new laptop but the problem persists. Below is part of the code:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption,setspace}
\captionsetup{font={sf,scriptsize,stretch=0.80},labelfont={bf,color=accessblue}}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,lipsum}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\usepackage{cuted}
\setlength\stripsep{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{sublemma}{Lemma}[lemma]
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\usepackage{multirow}      
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{Call Admission Control: A Survey}
\author{\uppercase{}\authorrefmark{1}, \IEEEmembership{},
\uppercase{\authorrefmark{1}},
\IEEEmembership{}}
\address[1]{Department of Electrical Engineering}
\tfootnote{This work was supported in part by the .... and ....}

\markboth
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}

\corresp{Corresponding author:  (e-mail:).}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract here
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
xxx, yyy
\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\section{Conclusion} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a link to the `ieeeaccess.cls` file required for the document style.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The class is quite buggy see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470144/2388 and more hits here.

Comment: Hi oliversm, I am new to latex, please clarify on that link you requested.