# Are there anyway to use forest package with IEEEACCESS template?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, ieeeaccess

I have been facing a problem to use Forest and Tikz package IEEE Access template. If I use these packages the title, abstract and index terms do not appear in the pdf. I find a solution here [Title, section headings disappears when I use \usepackage{forest} with IEEE Access template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470103/title-section-headings-disappears-when-i-use-usepackageforest-with-ieee-acce) but did not help me.
Is there any alternative solution to avoid the problem? Thank you.

MWE:

```latex
%% save the meaning of \year
\let\texyear\year
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}


\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{textcomp}

%\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{numprint}

\usepackage{float}

\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}   

\usepackage{pifont}%
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

%% temporary fix for loading expl3 and PGF
\let\ieeeaccessyear\year
\let\year\texyear
 
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\tikzset{parent/.style={align=left,text width=2cm,rounded corners=3pt},
    child/.style={align=left,text width=3.5cm,rounded corners=3pt}
}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}

\usepackage[]{subcaption}

\let\year\ieeeaccessyear

\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2020.DOI}

\title{Title}

\author{\uppercase{ABC}\authorrefmark{1,2}, and \uppercase{DEF}\authorrefmark{1}, \IEEEmembership{Member, ORG}}
\address[1]{Department of XYZ, XYZ University, PQR}

\address[2]{Department of MNO, RST University; RTY}

\markboth
{ABC \headeretal: TITLE}
{ABC \headeretal: TITLE}

\corresp{Corresponding author: DEF (e-mail: abc@abc.org).}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
facing a problem, to use Forest, and Tikz package, IEEE Access template
\end{keywords}

%\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{center}
    \begin{figure*}
%   \resizebox*{.85\linewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{forest}
            forked edges,
            for tree={
                grow'=east,
                draw=blue,
                line width=1.2pt, 
                edge={blue,line width=1.2pt},
                rounded corners,
                text width=4.2cm,
                node options={align=center}, anchor=parent
            }       
            [ABC, fill=pink!25, parent, s sep=3mm
            [B, for tree={child, fill=blue!15}
            [E, for tree={child, fill=blue!25}
            [{F,\\G\\H,\\I,
                %\\FEM,
                \\J}]]              % <<<<<1
            [K, for tree={child, fill=blue!25}
            [{L,\\T,\\P,\\X
            }]]                                     
            [L, for tree={child, fill=blue!25}
            [{A,\\T,\\B}]]                                  
            [S, for tree={child, fill=yellow!25}
            [{W,\\Q,\\Z}]]                                      
            [S, for tree={child, fill=purple!25}
            [{C,\\H,\\Y}]]                                  
            ]
            [C, for tree={child, fill=green!15}
            [P, for tree={child, fill=green!25}
            [{G}]                   
            ]
            [O, for tree={child, fill=green!25}
            [{V,\\D}]                               
            ]
            ]
            [D, for tree={child, fill=green!15}
            [S, for tree={child, fill=green!25}
            [{A,\\S,\\E}]               
            ]
            [Z, for tree={child, fill=red!5}
            [{R,\\H\cite{He2050},\\ M}] 
            ]
            ]
            ]
            ]
            ]
    \end{forest}
%}
    \captionsetup{type=figure}
    \captionof{figure}{\lipsum[2]}
    \label{tikz:taxonomy}
\end{figure*}
\end{center}

\section{Conclusions}

\lipsume[1]

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{BIBFILE}
 \EOD
\end{document}
```

Comment: We need an example of code that shows the issue.

Comment: AFAICS, IEEE Access uses its own class not ieeetran.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I have changed the question.

Comment: I have added MWE.

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: I have formatted the code. Thank you @user202729

Comment: If you consider suggestion given in the  @egreg answer on question in given link in your question,  you will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you @Zarko. It worked.

Comment: Thank you @egreg also. Your solution worked. Mistakenly I did not added the command \definecolor{accessblue}{RGB}{0,105,154}, which results the above problem.