# Asymptote Shading Gradient in HSV Color Space

Tags: asymptote, shading

Using asymptote I'm trying to fill shapes with gradient shading in the HSV color space.  Unfortunately, I think that HSV is not an available color space in asymptote.  However, asymptote does have the `hsv` function that returns a `pen` in the RGB color space.  I've used the following code to produce the two squares as shown.

```
unitsize(1inch);

// left square
pen p1 = hsv(240,1,1); // blue
pen p2 = hsv(  0,1,1); // red
axialshade(unitsquare, p1, (0,0), p2, (0,1));

// right square
real hband = 0.05;
for (real y = 0.0; y < 1.0; y += hband)
{
    fill(shift(1.2,y)*scale(1,hband)*unitsquare, hsv((1.0-y)*240,1,1));
}
```

The `axialshade` function is producing a gradient in the RGB color space on the left.  The right square illustrates the HSV gradient that I want.  However, it is produced manually by filling bands with solid HSV colors.  Is there a method to automatically produce a HSV gradient?

[image]

**EDIT:**  I see in comments at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59198/how-to-make-correct-shading-with-hsb-color-model) from 2012 that this color model is not supported by PDF.  If true, that probably means that I'm asking for the impossible.

Comment: If you're really determined to do it all in one area, you can specify the gradient as a postscript function (http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/functionshading.asy), but this will be slow to render. A probably better alternative is the latticeshade function, which should essentially allow you to smooth out your image on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @CharlesStaats for your great tip regarding the `latticeshade` function.

After doing more reading at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) I learned that the HSV color space consists simply of an RGB linear interpolation between the color sequence red--yellow--green--cyan--blue--magenta--red.  Trimming that sequence to fit my need gives the following code.

```
unitsize(1inch);

// left square
pen[][] pens = { {red}, {yellow}, {green}, {cyan}, {blue} };
latticeshade(unitsquare, pens);

// right square
real hband = 0.05;
for (real y = 0.0; y < 1.0; y += hband)
{
    fill(shift(1.2,y)*scale(1,hband)*unitsquare, hsv((1.0-y)*240,1,1));
}
```

[image]