# How to use the PANTONE color (SPOT color) in LaTeX2e version

Tags: color

How to use the PANTONE color (SPOT color) in LaTeX2e? Is there any package available?

Comment: Refer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141245/using-pantone-spot-colors-and-tikz-together

Comment: @Ambika Vanchinathan I referred that above said link, the given MWE is not working with my end, I am using normal LaTeX 2e (MiKTeX 2.9 latest version), I copied and pasted the xspotcolor.sty in the local working folder also.

Comment: I think it will be work in LuaTeX/XeLaTeX, but i want to use in normal LaTeX

Comment: @RCV Did you find the solution for this question?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see, the »xspotcolor« project hasn't been updated since 2013 and I fail to find the package on ctan. However, it consists of a couple of files and adding the code of xspotcolor.sty would not suffice.

But Javier Bezos has written the colorspace package, which also allows using pantone spotcolors. See here: [Package colorspace](http://ctan.org/pkg/colorspace), updated in October 2016! It supports pdftex, but not, as far as I understand the manual, compiling with LaTeX to a DVI.

If you can live with pdfTeX, this seems the way to go.

Comment: You are right - only pdftex and luatex. But contributions for other engines are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

[Take a look at `xespotcolor`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202175/using-pantone-spot-colors-in-xelatex/239610#239610) by Apostolos Syropoulos. It works well with XeLaTeX and TikZ and it did a great job for me.

Comment: Well, the OP expressed the wish to avoid XeLaTeX...