# How to define color PANTONE 300 c in LaTeX

Tags: color

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{newcolor}{cmyk}{.5,0,0,0}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{newcolor}{Sample text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This question could use a short bit of text explaining what the code snippet is supposed to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using `pdflatex` or `lualatex`, you can use the `colorspace` package:

You can give the alternate colour in either RGB, CMYK, or Lab.

However, I notice that `colorspace`converts the RGB values to CMYK, so maybe it's best to stick with CMYK or Lab alternate colours. (This is noted in the manual.) In fact I think it's definitely better not to use the RGB model, since the conversion to CMYK is done using the simple `xcolor` formulas which make no attempt to use colour management. So an RGB alternate colour will look quite different (as shown in the example below).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[illuminant=d50]{colorspace}
\definespotcolor{PANTONE 300 C (CMYK)}{PANTONE 300 C CMYK}{0.99,0.5,0.0,0.0}
\definespotcolor{PANTONE 300 C (RGB)}{PANTONE 300 C RGB}[RGB]{0 94 184}
\definespotcolor{PANTONE 300 C (Lab)}{PANTONE 300 C Lab}[alt=lab]{35.78,-9.69,-62.01/0.99,0.5,0.0,0.0}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{PANTONE 300 C (CMYK)}{PANTONE 300 C (alt = CMYK: 0.99, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0)}

\textcolor{PANTONE 300 C (RGB)}{PANTONE 300 C (alt = RGB: 0, 94, 184)}

\textcolor{PANTONE 300 C (Lab)}{PANTONE 300 C (alt = Lab: 35.78, -9.69, -62.01; illuminant = d50)}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

---

If you are using `xelatex`, you can use the `xespotcolor` package. This package isn't as feature filled as the `colorspace` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xespotcolor}

\NewSpotColorSpace{PANTONE}
\AddSpotColor{PANTONE}{PANTONE300C}{PANTONE\SpotSpace 300\SpotSpace C}{0.99 0.5 0 0}
\SetPageColorSpace{PANTONE}
\definecolor{PANTONE 300 C}{spotcolor}{PANTONE300C, 1.0}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{PANTONE 300 C}{PANTONE 300 C (alt = CMYK: 0.99, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0)}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Excellent and useful suggestion...you rocks...

Comment: `\NewSpotColorSpace{PANTONE}
\AddSpotColor{PANTONE} {PANTONE286UC100} {PANTONE\SpotSpace 286\SpotSpace UC} {0.90 0.75 0.01 0}
\definecolor{PANTONE286UC100}{cmyk}{0.90,0.75,0.01,0} \usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins} \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=PANTONE286UC100,boxrule=3pt,arc=5pt]
The content of this chapter has been published in the SRRW conference in 2017.  The work of this chapter is also extended to handle the ER problem. 
\end{tcolorbox}` what error I did? Kindly suggest....

Comment: @MadyYuvi it looks like the `\definecolor` line is wrong. You've just defined a CMYK colour.

Comment: Thanks, now the problem was fixed....

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{newcolor}{cmyk}{1,.56,0,.03} % PANTONE 300 c
% or ...
%       \definecolor{newcolor}{RGB}{0,94,184} 
%       \definecolor{newcolor}{HTML}{005EB8} 

\begin{document}
\textcolor{newcolor}{Sample text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the RGB or CMYK presentation is some approximate. Is it possible to define strong PANTONE color in LaTeX?

Comment: @Mr.Sandman See if [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338120/how-to-use-the-pantone-color-spot-color-in-latex2e-version) is what you are looking for.