# colorspace.sty vs \colorlet{current}{.}

Tags: color

When I try to capture the current color while a spot color (defined with `colorspace.sty`) is active I get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\color@&spot ...->\c@lor@arg {#2}\edef #1{\spc@ir 
                                                  \space cs \spc@ir \space C...
l.23 \colorlet{current}{.}
```

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,colorspace}
\definespotcolor{spot}{SPOT COLOR}{0,1,0,0}
\definecolor{cmyk}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}

\begin{document}
normal color

\color{cmyk}
cmyk color

\colorlet{current}{.}
\color{current}
current color

\color{spot}
spot color

\color{.}
period

\colorlet{current}{.}
\color{current}
current color

\colorlet{current}{.!50}
\color{current}
current color
\end{document}
```

I guess that in the background some changes happen when a spot color is activated that breaks the use of `.` (period) for the current color in `\colorlet`. `\color{.}` works fine though and even `\colorlet{current}{.!n}` for `n` ∈ {0, …, 99} works but not `.!100` so this is no workaround :-(

As far as I can tell the PDF output is correct, but I don’t want to ignore an error message …

Is it possible to workaround this or even better to fix it?

Comment: This problem occurred with the latest/frozen TeX Live 2016 and with an up to date TL 2017 (I din’t test other configurations).

Comment: I'm not surprised at all :-). I'll try to find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: @JavierBezos Good to hear, thank you very much in advance for your efforts! :-)

Comment: @JavierBezos: There’s also another case where the same error occurs, but I could not yet break it down to an MWE and now im hoping that the fix for the `\colorlet` problem also solves the other issue …

Comment: After `\color{spot}`, a call of `\extractcolorspec{.}{\foo}` will make `\foo` expand to `{&spot}{1}` which is obviously not good for `\colorlet` that uses the same mechanism. Any color defined with `\definespotcolor` will have the same behavior.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hi @JavierBezos, did you have some time to take a look? It would be great, if you could find a solution because the printing deadline for my project is coming :-/

Comment: @Tobi OK. I'll have a look at it tomorrow (I was working on the bidi support for babel/luatex, and I don't like to think of two things at once, but I'll make the effort :-)).

Comment: @Tobi Sorry, I couldn't find a workaroud. I just don't understand the internal "magic" in `xcolor` to handle the `.` notation. Very likely it would require patching some macros in the latter. The only solution that occurs to me is to write some macros to keep track of the current color and then make the computations by hand.

Comment: @JavierBezos. What a pity, but hanks for looking into it! I wrote an e-mail to the `xcolor` developer. Maybe he has an idea :-)

Comment: @JavierBezos Could you look into my answer? I'm not completly sure if using `\spc@getir` in this place is the correct thing to do.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'll have a look at it. (Just returned from hiking in the Schwartzwald.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error complains about an undefined `\spc@ir`. The following seems to define it, but I'm not completly sure that it gets the correct value (it seems to do, but Javier should better look into it too). The !50 in the output is not related, it happens only with xcolor too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colorspace}

\makeatletter
{
 \catcode`\&=11
 \gdef\color@&spot#1#2{%
  \ifdefined\spc@ir \else \spc@getir{\string\color@.}\fi
  \c@lor@arg{#2}%
  \edef#1{\spc@ir\space cs \spc@ir\space CS #2 sc #2 SC}}
}

\makeatother

\definespotcolor{spot}{SPOT COLOR}{0,1,0,0}
\definecolor{cmyk}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}

\begin{document}
normal color

\color{cmyk}
cmyk color

\colorlet{current}{.}
\color{current}
current color

\colorlet{current50}{.!50}
\color{current50}
current color

\color{spot}
spot color
\colorlet{spotcurrent}{.}

\color{.}
period

\colorlet{current}{.}

\color{current}
current color

\colorlet{current}{.!50}
\color{current}
current color

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! This seems to work. Herzlichen Dank!