# colorspace generates cryptic errors if used for a lable of a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-node, colorspace

I tried to use the package colorspace to get true colors for printing.
However, I obtain the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\color@&spot ...->\c@lor@arg {#2}\edef #1{\spc@ir\space cs \spc@ir \space C
1.9 \node[label={[MyColor]:Hello}] at (2,0){};
```

and

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\color@&spot ...->edef #1{\spc@ir \space cs \spc@ir\space CD #2 sc #2 SC}
1.9 \node[label={[MyColor]:Hello}] at (2,0){};
```

running the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colorspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definespotcolor{MyColor}{PANTONE 2736 C}{0.97,0.95,0,0}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[MyColor] (0,0) rectangle(1,1);
\node[label={[green]:Hello}] at (2,-1){};
\node[label={[MyColor]:Hello}] at (2,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Both errors occur in line 9. Using the color for filling a rectangle in line 7 is no problem and using a standard color for the label in line 8 works, too.
In particular, the output is correct:

[image: correct output]

The syntax of \definespotcolor is

```
\definespotcolor{<latex-name>}{<PDF-name>}{<CMYK-equivalent>}
```

Comment: As a workaround `\node[label={\color{MyColor}Hello}] at (2,0){};`

Comment: can you change the order of tikz and colorspace loading?

Comment: Changing of order won't change the result. Your workaround worked, @samcarter, thank you!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385570/2388. My patch works for your example too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround I suggest to use `\color{MyColor}` syntax instead of `[MyColor]:`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colorspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definespotcolor{MyColor}{PANTONE 2736 C}{0.97,0.95,0,0}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[MyColor] (0,0) rectangle(1,1);
\node[label={\color{green}Hello}] at (2,-1){};
\node[label={\color{MyColor}Hello}] at (2,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```