# tcolorbox.sty and tikz not supporting spot color (using dvips)

Tags: tikz-pgf

My codes are follows:

```
% Using spot colors with xcolor and pstricks.
% process with:
% $ latex xcpst
% $ dvips -h tex.pro -h xcolor.pro -h spot.pro filename.dvi
\begin{filecontents*}{PANTONE2925C.pro}
% spot.pro
TeXDict begin
/SpotsCMYK [0.85 0.24 0 0] def
/Pantone2925CSpot (Pantone2925C) def
/Pantone2925CDef SpotsCMYK aload pop Pantone2925CSpot
findcmykcustomcolor def
/XC@Pantone2925C{ Pantone2925CDef 1.0 setcustomcolor}XCdef
/XC@Pantone2925C100{ Pantone2925CDef 1.0 setcustomcolor}XCdef
end
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[prologue]{xcolor}%
\input colordvi%%

\definecolor{Pantone2925C}{cmyk}{1 0 0 0}
\colorlet{Pantone2925C100}{Pantone2925C}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,calc,positioning,shapes,shadows}

\makeatletter
\newbox\tcolorboxstut%
\setbox\tcolorboxstut=\hbox{hy}%
\newdimen\tcolorboxstutdimen%
\tcolorboxstutdimen=\ht\tcolorboxstut%
\advance\tcolorboxstutdimen by -1.75\p@%
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}%
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\tcbset{enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=Pantone2925C,boxrule=3pt,breakable,arc=5pt,before skip=17.5pt,after skip=16pt,bottom=\tcolorboxstutdimen}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox} {\bf Experimental research} examines how a treatment causally
  affects an outcome by assigning varying values of the treatment
  variable to different observations and measuring their corresponding
  values of the outcome variable.
\end{tcolorbox}

\textcolor{Pantone2925C}{For Test}
\end{document}
```

I am using `LaTeX` then `dvips -Ppdf -h tex.pro -h xcolor.pro -h PANTONE2925C.pro test.dvi` and then `PS2PDF` to get the PDF output.

[image]
Output generated successfully, but the `tcolorbox` still shows in `CMYK` only, but the same time, the text `For Test` showed in `Pantone` color, how can I achieve this? Please suggest...

**EDIT**

As `Ulrike` advise, I've tried with `colorspace.sty` with `PDFLaTeX` and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{colorspace}
\definespotcolor{PANTONE286UC100}{PANTONE286UC}{0.90,0.75,0.01,0}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=PANTONE286UC100,boxrule=3pt,arc=5pt]
The content of this chapter has been published in the SRRW conference in 2017.  The work of this chapter is also extended to handle the ER problem. 
\end{tcolorbox}

\textcolor{PANTONE286UC100}{This is for test}
\end{document}
```

But it produced the empty page, if I change the color from `colframe=PANTONE286UC100` to `colframe=cyan` then it works, please advise how to get Spot color for `colframe`....

Comment: Spotcolors with dvips currently works only with some (still quite experimental) expl3 code (l3color). With pdflatex  you can use the colorspace package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've tried with `colorspace.sty` with `PDFLaTeX` as you suggested, but still not able to get the `colframe` in `Spot` color, kindly advise....

Comment: use the color once *before*  the tcolorbox.

Comment: I'm just mentioning https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17757/86 here to link the two questions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your suggestion, I've followed you suggestion like `\textcolor{PANTONE286UC100}{This is for test}
\begin{tcolorbox}....` but no better output, can you please suggest??....